# How to solve Diamond problem with pure virtual function

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

```
class base
{
  public:
     virtual void display() = 0;
};

class derived : virtual public base
{
 public:
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Display of derived : " << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived1 : virtual public base
{
  public:
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Display of derived : " << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived2 : public derived, derived1
{

};
```

I am taking one pure virtual function into base class. I am using virtual keyword while creating derived and derived1 class which is inherited from my base class, and I finally created derived2 class which inherit from derived and derived1 ,Then I will get error "derived2:ambigous inheritance of base::void(display)" How to resolve this error ?

Comment: provide  void derived2::display(void)

Comment: How can the compiler decide which `display` to use between the two if you don't tell?

Comment: Well, you've solved the diamond problem. What you have is just a multiple inheritance problem now.

Comment: A pig says "oink, oink". A dog says "woof, woof". Based on this information, can you tell what a pigdog says?

Comment: Nitpick: either you have `using namespace std;` and you don't use `std::` qualification anywhere, or you use it everywhere!

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Using the syntax `(void)` for the argument list is untypical of C++ style; it's leftover from primitive C.

Comment: "_Then I will get error "derived2:ambigous inheritance of base::void(display)"_" Which compiler provides this (IMHO poor) error diagnostic?

Comment: You should reconsider your design IMO. If two classes each have their idea of what `display` does, they probably each have their own idea of many things, and they might not be compatible. Just because virtual inheritance was used doesn't mean that sharing of that base class is actually possible.

Answer (score 5):

You need to decide which of the two is the derived method, since both derived and derived1 provide an implementation.

Using non-virtual functions, the solution would be more straightforward: by simply writing `using derived::display` or `using derived1::display`

But you're using virtual functions, so you will need to add a final overriding function.
It can be done like so:

```
class derived2 : public derived, derived1 {
  public:
    void display() override {
      derived::display(); // or derived1::display();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Both derived::display() and derived1::display() must be marked virtual as well". No, this is not necessary. It is a good style to mark them `override` though.